# change db:5432 to 127.0.0.1:5432 in docker-compose file

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

In my docker-compose.yml file i have two images. I am linking db to my myapp container with node.js application and everything works as long as my sequelize database host is db.

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize(DATABASE, USERNAME, PASSWORD, {
    "host": "db",
    "port": 5432,
    "dialect": "postgres"
});
```

Is it possible to configure docker-compose.yml so I can use 127.0.0.1 as my database host instead of db?

```
db:
  image: postgres
  ports:
  - "5432:5432"
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: user
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pw
    POSTGRES_DB: db
myapp:  
  build: .
  ports:
    - "8081:8081"
  links:
    - db
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already publish port `5432` to host, so you can just replace `db` with `127.0.0.1`. If you use docker-machine you should specify its IP (not 127.0.0.1)

Answer (score 0):

In `myapp` you can use `net: service:db` which should let you connect to localhost, but why would you want to do that?